# Replace and delete PDF File

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I am using the following piece of code to delete the old PDF and replace the old one with the new one but with no result. Is is possible to perform this operation on PDF files? As, throughout the net I see that these functions are used for .txt,.xls.doc...etc file types. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please help...

```
private void ListFieldNames(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            string pdfTemplate = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\PassportApplicationForm_Main_English_V1.0.pdf";
            //var newFile = pdfTemplate;
            string newFile = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\_PassportApplicationForm_Main_English_V1.0.pdf";
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                //ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)pdfTemplate);
                //PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
                    var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;
                    foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
                    {
                        //Replace Address Form field with my custom data
                        if (fieldKey.Contains("Surname"))
                        {
                            form.SetField(fieldKey, s);
                        }    
                    }
                    // set form fields


                    //form.SetField("Address", s);
                    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    stamper.Close();

                }

            }
            File.Copy(newFile, pdfTemplate);
            File.Delete(pdfTemplate);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and analyzed what it is doing?

Comment: I've got no experience with iText or iTextSharp, but there seem to be some oddities in this code. Why are you looping over all the pages but not using the page number anywhere? You seem to be overwriting the new file with the exact same data `NumberofPages - 1` times by doing `new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)` in each iteration of the loop. Also, why are you opening two `PdfReader`s and casting a `string` to a `string`?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good to me, just change:

```
File.Copy(newFile, pdfTemplate);
File.Delete(pdfTemplate);
```

change to:

```
File.Delete(pdfTemplate);
File.Copy(newFile, pdfTemplate);
```

You can't copy a file if a file already exists at its location with the same name as it.
Delete existing file first.